# How to select a specific column in a define named range an search for a value and replace with other value in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a dynamic predefined (in other sub routines) range. Let's assume that is from A1 to E100 and has a name RngToSearch1, I have another dynamic range in the same sheet of the first, named RngToSearch2 and let says its start from A102 to F150. For both ranges the first row is the header with a given column name(maybe one range have to row for headers), (Month nr, Month name, Product Name, SubProductName, Sales Amount) and for the second range (Company name, company id, prod name, subprod name,qta,sales amount)

In a table, in a different sheet, I have specified for each Range the column name which appears a subtotal and the new name of subtotal. so let say that for the first range, the subtotal appears for Month Name and Product Name, and for the second range the subtotal for Company name and prod name).
The subtotal name is generic, Subtotal Result.

So I need a code that searches in RngToSearch1 only in the column Month Name and  Product Name and only till the last row of the range, and replaces the generic label of subtotal with one that I assign to that subtotal, in this case Result per Month, Result x Company name. the same thing to the other ranges.

so the number of range in the same sheet is dynamic, in this case I just use only 2, but they can be more.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I read twice but didn't understand what's the problem. Too many words and not clear description.
All that I can guess, you need a collection of ranges
if it's so then you will have something like below:

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100, 200))
MsgBox rng(1, 3)'you can work with dimensions of range as with an array

Dim coll As New Collection'declare a new collection 
coll.Add rng'add an element
coll(1) = rng' we can add by index 
MsgBox coll(1)(1, 3)'and return by index and work as with range
End Sub
```

Comment: I just update a picture to clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

object Range has property .Columns

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100, 200))
rng.Columns(1).Select' selects column in a range
End Sub
```

You can work with range as with sheet